# Excel VBA Code to subtract the quantity from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 sheets which name are `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`. All sheets have the same columns. I have been using a `SUMIFS` formula in `Sheet2.Range("C2")`:

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$15,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$15,'Sheet2'!B2,
Sheet1!$A$2:$A$15,'Sheet2'!A2,Sheet1!$D$2:$D$15,"="&'Sheet2'!D2)-
SUMIFS(Sheet3!$C$2:$C$15,Sheet3!$B$2:$B$15,'Sheet2'!B2,
Sheet3!$A$2:$A$15,'Sheet2'!A2,Sheet3!$D$2:$D$15,"="&'Sheet2'!D2)
```

I have prepared below code which takes the value of `Sheet1` `Column C` by matching `Column A`, `B` and `D` with `Sheet2`, and paste the result in `Sheet2` `Column C`.

I have been looking for a way to to subtract the `Sheet3` `Column C` quantity from Sheet1 `Column C` by matching `Column A,` `B` and `D` then its result should be pasted into `Sheet2` `Column C`.

The file and data are attached here:

```
Dim dict As Object
    Dim searchrange As Range        
    With Sheet1
        Dim last_y As Long
        Dim i As Long
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        last_y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To last_y    
        dict(.Cells(i, 1).Value & .Cells(i, 2).Value & .Cells(i, 4).Value) = _
            dict(.Cells(i, 1).Value & .Cells(i, 2).Value & .Cells(i, 4).Value) + _
           .Cells(i, 3).Value                    
        Next i
    End With
    
    With Sheet3
        last_y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To last_y
        .Cells(i, 3).Value = dict(.Cells(i, 1).Value & .Cells(i, 2).Value & _
            .Cells(i, 4).Value)
        Next i
    End With
```

Comment: What should go into Sheet2? When sheet1-ABD is not in sheet3?  When sheet3-ABD is not in sheet1?

Comment: thank you for sparing time @donPablo  What should go into Sheet2? Then Exit Sub nothing should be happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is a direct comparison then using a Dictionary is probably not the best method. I would just iterate through all 3 sheets as long as its under 100k rows. You could get fancy with .Find and .FindNext but the easiest is just a good old For Loop.

If I'm understanding your request, you need all values from Sheet 1 to be subtracted by a corresponding value from sheet 3 (if it exists) and then outputted into the matching row of sheet 2 (if it exists). Here's how I would do that:

```
Sub rowMatch()
    Dim a As String, b As String, c As Double, d As String
    For i = 2 To Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'Grab the Sheet1 values
        a = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Text
        b = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Text
        c = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value
        d = Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Text
        
        'Check Sheet3
        For j = 2 To Sheet3.Cells(Sheet3.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If Sheet3.Cells(j, 1).Text = a _
               And Sheet3.Cells(j, 2).Text = b _
               And Sheet3.Cells(j, 4).Text = d _
               Then
               c = c - Sheet3.Cells(j, 3).Value
            End If
        Next j
        
        'Put into Sheet2
        For k = 2 To Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If Sheet2.Cells(k, 1).Text = a _
               And Sheet2.Cells(k, 2).Text = b _
               And Sheet2.Cells(k, 4).Text = d _
               Then
               Sheet2.Cells(k, 3) = c
            End If
        Next k
    Next i
End Sub
```

Edit: To further improve this, you may want to make the code more flexible by only comparing the strings after doing operations like UCASE() and TRIM(). And you may want to add in exceptions for if a, b, or d are blank. Maybe in those cases you want to allow partial matches. My example was just the basic idea.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much appreciated that you explained it well and suggested other solution as well. But when i run the code nothing happens. I have been trying to find out what is the problem but nothing found

Comment: Oh, whoops I did compare column 3 to b by accident. I'll correct it with an edit.